# How to cancel a task and throw an exception without calling IsCancellationRequested or ThrowIfCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, .net, task, cancellation

I create 2 tasks. `Task1` runs a long calculations (`SingleLongMethod`), `Task2` has to cancel `Task1` in the middle of the calculations.

The solution I found is to call 
`token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` or `token.IsCancellationRequested`.

The question is: can I throw an Exception in the `Task1`, automatically after calling `token.Cancel()` in `Task2` without repeatedly calling `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        token.Register(() => 
        {
            //throw new Exception("Help!");
        });

        SingleLongMethod();
    });

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        StopMethod();
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void SingleLongMethod()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test pcb");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I was stopped!");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End!");
    }
}
private static void StopMethod()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if (i == 5)
                tokenSource.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine("Monitoring state");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Help!");
    }
}
```

I tried to throw and exception in registering callbacks but it didn't work out.

Comment: I corrected "`Task2` has to cancel `Task2`" into "`Task2` has to cancel `Task1`". Is that what you mean?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I suspect the real problem is far easier to solve. This code won't compile as `token` isn't defined. There's no reason to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` either.

Comment: @Panagiotis I tried inefficiently to simplify my problem to general case. The point is I'm controlling a device in the Task1 and in the Task2 I'm monitoring mechanical state of this device(is it opened or closed). When Task2 detect that someone try to open device manually, I need to cancel Task1 immediately

Answer (score 0):

Forcing a running thread to exit is a bad practice and not supported in .NET because the threads are managed and controlled by the runtime that does not even allow you to do this.

There are 2 ways to end the execution of a task:

1. The way that you are currently using, which is already good enough.
2. Instead of using a `CancellationToken`, you could `await` a task that is cancelled.

Example:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var cancelTask = Task.CompletedTask;

    var task1 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test pcb");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                await cancelTask;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I was stopped!");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End!");
        }
    });

    var task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    cancelTask = Task.FromException(new OperationCanceledException());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Monitoring state");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("Help!");
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```